zoom issue in blender
I am new to Blender and have been doing tutorials through Blender Guru. I am working on the chair tutorial and have encountered a problem I've never had.
For some reason my mouse is not able to zoom or pan on this specific Blender file. I go to other files I have and my mouse works perfectly fine. Why can't I zoom or pan on this specific file?

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

this is a common problem, there should be an answer somewhere, press Shift C or maybe try this trick, in the Preferences > Orbit & Pan, activate Auto Depth? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmXEtKW5otQ

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
